# Finding Average Penalty from AMAT

Tags: performance, caching, memory, cpu-architecture

I can calculate penalty when I have a single cache. But I'm unsure what to do when I am presented with two L1 caches (one for data and one for instruction) that are accessed in parallel. I'm also unsure what to do when I'm presented with clock cycles instead of actual time such as ns.

How do I calculate the average miss penalty using these new parameters?

Do I just use the formula two times and then average the miss penalty or is there more to this?

```
AMAT = hit time + miss rate * miss penalty
```

For example I have the following values:

```
AMAT = 4 clock cycles  
L1 data access = 2 clock cycle (also hit time)  
L1 instruction access = 2 clock cycle (also hit time)  
60% of instructions are loads and stores  
L1 instruction miss rate = 1%  
L1 data miss rate = 3%
```

How would these values fit into AMAT?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I see it, since the L1 Instruction Cache and the L1 Data Cache are accessed in parallel, you should compute AMAT for Instructions and AMAT for data, and then **take the largest value** as the final AMAT.

In your example since the Data Miss Rate is higher than Instruction Miss Rate you can consider that during the time the CPU waits for data, it solves all the misses on the instruction cache.

If the measure unit is *cycles* you do the same as if it were nanoseconds. If you know the frequency of your processor, you can convert back the AMAT in nanoseconds.

Comment: So in my example, the AMAT would be the one for data because of the higher miss rate?  Therefore I can calculate the average miss penalty for both accesses by 4-2 / .03?

Comment: Yes. This is how I interpret your question.

Comment: What about having 60% of instructions that are loads and stores does that fit anywhere into AMAT?

Comment: I think that would have mattered only if the amount of load and stores would have been much smaller. Of course if there are hidden constraints (e.g. Your cpu has a single execution port) this changes the solution.

Comment: I don't think that this is correct.  At least it is not how AMAT is typically calculated.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

The **average memory access time (AMAT)** is typically calculated by taking the total number of instructions and dividing it by the total number of cycles spent servicing the memory request.

#### Details

On page B-17 of [Computer Architecture a Quantiative Approach, 5th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012383872X) AMAT is defined as:

> Average memory access time = % instructions x (Hit time + instruction miss rate x miss penalty) + % data x (Hit time + Data miss rate x miss penalty)`.

As you can see in this formula each instruction counts for a single memory access and the instructions that operate on data (load/store) constitute an additional memory access.

Note that there are many simplifying instructions that are made when using AMAT, and depending on the performance analysis that you want to perform.  The same textbook I quotes earlier notes that:

> In summary, although the state of the art in defining and measuring
>   memory stalls for out-of-order processors is complex, be aware of the
>   issues because they significantly affect performance. The complexity
>   arises because out-of-order processors tolerate some latency due to
>   cache misses without hurting performance. Consequently, designers
>   normally use simulators of the out-of-order processor and memory when
>   evaluating trade-offs in the memory hierarchy to be sure that an
>   improvement that helps the average memory latency actually helps
>   program performance.

My point of including this quote is that in practice AMAT is used for getting an approximate comparison between various different option.  And as a result there are always simplifying assumptions used.  But generally the memory accesses for instructions and data are added together to get a total number of accesses when calculating AMAT, rather than being calculated separately.

Comment: That seemf fair. Most probable your answer is the correct one because it'a a didactic one. I was considering an OOO current CPU which we usually see in practice.